# Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://airportparkingspecials.com/dam1.php}

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, response

I am getting null response in place of value.

here is my APi interface

```
@POST("dam1.php")
    @Multipart
    fun booking(
        @Part("productDesc")productDesc:String,
        @Part("startDate")startDate:String,
        @Part("endDate")endDate:String,
        @Part("firstName")firstName:String,
        @Part("lastName")lastName:String,
        @Part("email")email:String,
        @Part("phone")phone:String,
        @Part("address")address:String,
        @Part("address2")address2:String,
        @Part("city")city:String,
        @Part("country")country:String,
        @Part("state")state:String,
        @Part("zip")zip:String,
        @Part("cardNumber")cardNumber:String,
        @Part("expiryMonth")expiryMonth:String,
        @Part("expiryYear")expiryYear:String,
        @Part("cardCode")cardCode:String,
        @Part("sub_total")sub_total:String,
        @Part("taxfees")taxfees:String
    ): Call<Confirmation>
```

here is data class

```
data class Confirmation(
    val Data: Data,
    val transactionID: Any
)

data class Data(
    val address: String,
    val address2: String,
    val cardCode: String,
    val cardNumber: String,
    val city: String,
    val country: String,
    val email: String,
    val endDate: String,
    val expiryMonth: String,
    val expiryYear: String,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val phone: String,
    val productDesc: String,
    val startDate: String,
    val state: String,
    val sub_total: String,
    val taxfees: String,
    val zip: String
)
```

Callback

```
            call.enqueue(object :Callback<Confirmation>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Confirmation>, t: Throwable{
                }
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Confirmation>, response: Response<Confirmation>) {
                    d("Response",response.code().toString())
                }
            })
```

Whenever I call the api , the statuscode is 200 but the response body is always coming as null. the message i received is this :

Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://airportparkingspecials.com/dam1.php}

Comment: did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, i changed "Multipart" to "FormUrlEncoded" and now it's woking fine.